# Handle multiple product impressions and promotions in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm implementing GTM on an e-commerce site. The problem I have is that we have lots of products and lots of promotions on the same page and Google is limiting the size of the request. That means that not everything pushed onto the dataLayer is getting sent to their servers.

On my last try, I separated the data onto different objects, and pushed them both to the dataLayer

[image]

But when I inspect the requests made to Google with a plugin like HttpFox, only the data from dataLayer[3] is getting sent.

What can I be doing wrong?
How does google expect us to send data in large e-commerce sites?

I've search a lot about this topic but couldn't find any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the first batch with the pageload, and every subsequent data with an GA event. You always need an interaction event (pageview or event) to send enhanced ecommerce data.

At the moment, as you have pointed out, GTM will pick the last thing you pushed to the datalayer (since the keys are the same the previous data is overwritten in the internal GTM data structure, which is an object rather than an array of objects).

So you push the additional data, add a custom GTM event ( e.g.`{"event":"addData"}` and build  a trigger that fires on that custom event. GTM will pick the lastest ecommerce data from the datalayer and use it for GA. After the tag went through you push the next batch etc.

Comment: Thanks Eike, I'll try this method and will come back to this post with the result

Comment: So this actually works, I guess it's the only way to implement GTM on large sites. An offtopic question is, why is the byte-limit so small? Why can't we send large collections of data at once?

Comment: Limit is 8KB. POST request do not, in theory, have a size limit; I assume this has more to do with how the data is handled by Googles server-side collection engine (maybe 8KB chunks are a particularly good size for processing). But you'd need to ask a Google engineer.  But I agree that GTM should have some built-in facility to deal with this, since large product lists are not that uncommon when one uses enhanced e-commerce.